# Dynamic-cast from 'const b2Shape*' to 'b2PolygonShape*' casts away qualifiers?

Tags: ios, casting, box2d, polygon, shapes

I am simply trying to create a `b2PolygonShape` from a `b2Shape` but I am having an error that says: `Dynamic-cast from 'const b2Shape*' to 'b2PolygonShape*' casts away qualifiers`

This is my code:

```
const b2Shape *s = fix2.shape;
b2PolygonShape *p = dynamic_cast<b2PolygonShape*>(s);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the `const` qualifier that the compiler complains about. The solution is to 
declare `p` as pointer to `const b2PolygonShape`:

```
const b2PolygonShape *p = dynamic_cast<const b2PolygonShape*>(s);
```